Debian 11 DHCP Configuration
I am having trouble configuring an interface to use DHCP in Debian 11. Thus, I have my static attempt in /etc/network/interfaces like this:
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp1s3
allow-hotplug enp1s3
### iface enp1s3 inet dhcp ### sink in hell!!!
iface enp1s3 inet static
  address 192.168.0.7
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.0.1
  dns-nameservers 181.213.132.3

impossibilities: using systemctl, nmcli, ifconfig, and many others, since I only achieved to install it. (no internet = no apt-get install)
ip a command doesn't seem to show me everything I need. I obtained the gateway, netmask and dns, by a windows computer connected to this home network.
after it all set, It only pings itself. pinging dns, google's dns, router, broadcast, gives nothing. This machine is old and using two ethernet devices, although it only shows one in ip addr command. I know the cable is working because I tested in the windows machine.
I'd like to know if I either set anything wrong or if the board is obsolete and in need of any firmware or summoning some demons to work.

edit 1: more details.
# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s3: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:17:31:77:a3:c9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.7/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global enp1s3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

and
# ip route
default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp1s3 onlink linkdown 
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp1s3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.7 linkdown

I don't understand why the state of the link is "down", but in between brackets says it's "up". (I tried, several times, both ifup/ifdown and ip link set up/down. Something seems to be a little off, here.)

What is the output of ping google.com?

Does Debian 12 work? Using newer versions of Debian often help as the kernel is much newer and thus supports more drivers.

What does your syslog say when you use an actual DHCP configuration?

Also, is this wifi or wired?

I reverted your edit marking the question as solved.  If Jason C's answer helped you solve the question, then consider accepting that answer. If you found your own answer, then add it as a separate answer and accept it later.  Accepting an answer marks the issue as having been resolved.

Please don't deface your question. All contributions are licensed under Creative Commons, and this site is collaboratively edited, like Wikipedia. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/editing  This is also explained in the tour which you should have been invited to read.

@RRF_user24527818 Sorry, but this is how this site works.  You contribute a question, others edit it, somebody gives an answer, someone else edits that, and people learn from both question and answer.

Assuming this is a wired connection, it says NO-CARRIER, which means the other end isn't responding at a very low protocol level.
So maybe this sounds obvious but, try a different ethernet cable (check yours if you have a cable tester, or a different machine to test the cable with), and also verify the link light actually comes on when you plug in the cable.
If using a known-working cable fails, try a different port on your router (perhaps the port is damaged).
If that fails, it's possible that the jack or network card on your machine is damaged or bad.
In any case, verify that the link light comes up. If it doesn't, it points to one of the above.

+1, and there are some more options under eth0 NO-CARRIER, ifconfig shows no IP address or under external sources like archlinux.org - Ethernet connection randomly goes to NO-CARRIER

@RRF_user24527818 TBH, with the info you've provided, I'd try a different network interface at this point, if you have one laying around. Debian 11 doesn't have any particular networking issues that I know of so this really sounds like a hardware issue (or I suppose a possible driver + hardware issue) to me.
